# Does "Fam, the Silver Wing" need a separate tag from Last Exile?

Tags: discussion, tags, lumping-and-splitting

[*Ginyoku no Fam*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10336/Last_Exile:_Ginyoku_no_Fam) ("Fam, the Silver Wing") is the sequel to [*Last Exile*](http://myanimelist.net/anime/97/Last_Exile). Is the former ([fam-the-silver-wing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fam-the-silver-wing)) sufficiently different from the latter ([last-exile](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/last-exile)) as to warrant a separate tag? My sense is no, based on plot synopses, but I haven't watched either of these shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they should be separate since that series is it's own original story (though there are cameos from the preceding series) rather than a continuation of it's predecessor.

This is not unlike the relationship between "A Certain Magical Index" and "A Certain Scientific Railgun" series.

Comment: Sounds good. I've updated the corresponding tag wikis to reflect the relationship between the two shows.